# Why doesn't my PHP code Submit the application to my email?

Tags: php, html

I cannot figure out why my PHP code will not send the application I have to my email. The website is live and still has a lot of bugs but I’m trying to figure out why after I submit the application why won’t it go to my email. If someone could please help me out or point me into a direction were I could learn more about it I would greatly appreciate it as I am new to code.

PHP:

```
   <?php
if ($POST) {
    $firstname  = $_POST['firstname'];
    $middleinitial = $_POST['middleinitial'];
    $lastname  = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email2  = $_POST['emailaddress'];
    $form_dob_month  = $_POST['month'];
    $form_dob_day  = $_POST['day'];
    $form_dob_year  = $_POST['year'];
    $social  = $_POST['socialsecurity#'];
    $Driver  = $_POST['driverlicense#'];
    $cellphone  = $_POST['cellphone'];
    $address  = $_POST['streetaddress'];
    $zip  = $_POST['zipcode'];
    $city  = $_POST['city'];
    $form_state  = $_POST['state'];
    $timeataddress  = $_POST['timeatpresentaddress'];
    $rent  = $_POST['monthlyrent/mortgagepayment'];
    $jobtitle  = $_POST['presentjobtitle'];
    $employer  = $_POST['presentemployer'];
    $employerphone  = $_POST['employerphonenumber'];
    $jobtime  = $_POST['timeatpresentjob'];
    $grossincome  = $_POST['monthlygrossincome'];
 }   
    //send email   
    mail("iamdrivingleads@yahoo.com", "email enquiry", $text, "From:" . $email);


?>
```

HTML:

```
    <section id="faq">
            <div class="row pad-large">
<div class="row">
            <div class="large-8 large-centered columns pad-bottom-small">
                <div id="faq-form" class="text-center">
                    <form method = "_POST" action = "mail.php">
                        <input id="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
                        <input id="middleinitial" type="text" placeholder="Middle Name" />
                        <input id="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
                        <input id="email2" type="text" placeholder="E-mail address" />
                        <select id="form_dob_month" name="dob_month">
    <option value="-">Date</option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">Febuary</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
 <select id="form_dob_day" name="dob_day">
    <option value="-">Of</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
 <select id="form_dob_year" name="dob_year">
    <option value="-">Birth</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2009">2009</option>
    <option value="2008">2008</option>
    <option value="2007">2007</option>
    <option value="2006">2006</option>
    <option value="2005">2005</option>
    <option value="2004">2004</option>
    <option value="2003">2003</option>
    <option value="2002">2002</option>
    <option value="2001">2001</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="1999">1999</option>
    <option value="1998">1998</option>
    <option value="1997">1997</option>
    <option value="1996">1996</option>
    <option value="1995">1995</option>
    <option value="1994">1994</option>
    <option value="1993">1993</option>
    <option value="1992">1992</option>
    <option value="1991">1991</option>
    <option value="1990">1990</option>
    <option value="1989">1989</option>
    <option value="1988">1988</option>
    <option value="1987">1987</option>
    <option value="1986">1986</option>
    <option value="1985">1985</option>
    <option value="1984">1984</option>
    <option value="1983">1983</option>
    <option value="1982">1982</option>
    <option value="1981">1981</option>
    <option value="1980">1980</option>
    <option value="1979">1979</option>
    <option value="1978">1978</option>
    <option value="1977">1977</option>
    <option value="1976">1976</option>
    <option value="1975">1975</option>
    <option value="1974">1974</option>
    <option value="1973">1973</option>
    <option value="1972">1972</option>
    <option value="1971">1971</option>
    <option value="1970">1970</option>
    <option value="1969">1969</option>
    <option value="1968">1968</option>
    <option value="1967">1967</option>
    <option value="1966">1966</option>
    <option value="1965">1965</option>
    <option value="1964">1964</option>
    <option value="1963">1963</option>
    <option value="1962">1962</option>
    <option value="1961">1961</option>
    <option value="1960">1960</option>
    <option value="1959">1959</option>
    <option value="1984">1958</option>
    <option value="1983">1957</option>
    <option value="1982">1956</option>
    <option value="1981">1955</option>
    <option value="1980">1954</option>
    <option value="1979">1953</option>
    <option value="1978">1952</option>
    <option value="1977">1951</option>
    <option value="1976">1950</option>
    <option value="1975">1949</option>
    <option value="1974">1948</option>
    <option value="1973">1947</option>
    <option value="1972">1946</option>
    <option value="1971">1945</option>
    <option value="1970">1944</option>
    <option value="1969">1943</option>
    <option value="1968">1942</option>
    <option value="1967">1941</option>
    <option value="1966">1940</option>
    <option value="1965">1939</option>
    <option value="1964">1938</option>
    <option value="1963">1937</option>
    <option value="1962">1936</option>
    <option value="1961">1935</option>
    <option value="1960">1934</option>
    <option value="1959">1933</option>
    <option value="1961">1932</option>
    <option value="1960">1931</option>
    <option value="1959">1930</option>
    <option value="1984">1929</option>
    <option value="1983">1928</option>
    <option value="1982">1927</option>
    <option value="1981">1926</option>
    <option value="1980">1925</option>
    <option value="1979">1924</option>
    <option value="1978">1923</option>
    <option value="1977">1922</option>
    <option value="1976">1921</option>
    <option value="1975">1920</option>
    <option value="1974">1919</option>
    <option value="1973">1918</option>
    <option value="1972">1917</option>
    <option value="1971">1916</option>
    <option value="1970">1915</option>
    <option value="1969">1914</option>
    <option value="1968">1913</option>
    <option value="1967">1912</option>
    <option value="1966">1911</option>
    <option value="1965">1910</option>
</select>               
                        <input id="social" type="text" placeholder="Social Security #" />
                        <input id="Driver" type="text" placeholder="Driver License #" />
                        <input id="cellphone" type="text" placeholder="Cell Phone" />
                        <input id="address" type="text" placeholder="Street Address" />
                        <input id="zip" type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" />
                        <input id="city" type="text" placeholder="City" />
                        <select id="form_state" name="State">
                        <option value="-">State</option>
                        <option value="1">Alabama</option>
                        <option value="2">Alaska</option>
                        <option value="3">Arizona</option>
                        <option value="4">Arkansas</option>
                        <option value="5">California</option>
                        <option value="6">Colorado</option>
                        <option value="7">Connecticut</option>
                        <option value="8">Delaware</option>
                        <option value="9">Florida</option>
                        <option value="10">Georgia</option>
                        <option value="11">Hawaii</option>
                        <option value="12">Idaho</option>
                        <option value="13">Illinois</option>
                        <option value="14">Indiana</option>
                        <option value="15">Iowa</option>
                        <option value="16">Kansas</option>
                        <option value="17">Kentucky</option>
                        <option value="18">Louisiana</option>
                        <option value="19">Maine</option>
                        <option value="20">Maryland</option>
                        <option value="21">Massachusetts</option>
                        <option value="22">Michigan</option>
                        <option value="23">Minnesota</option>
                        <option value="24">Mississippi</option>
                        <option value="25">Missouri</option>
                        <option value="26">Montana</option>
                        <option value="27">Nebraska </option>
                        <option value="28">Nevada</option>
                        <option value="29">New Hampshire</option>
                        <option value="30">New Jersey</option>
                        <option value="31">New Mexico</option>
                        <option value="32">New York</option>
                        <option value="33">North Carolina</option>
                        <option value="34">North Dakota</option>
                        <option value="35">Ohio</option>
                        <option value="36">Oklahoma</option>
                        <option value="37">Oregon</option>
                        <option value="38">Pennsylvania</option>
                        <option value="39">Rhode Island</option>
                        <option value="40">South Carolina</option>
                        <option value="41">South Dakota</option>
                        <option value="42">Tennessee</option>
                        <option value="43">Texas</option>
                        <option value="44">Utah</option>
                        <option value="45">Vermont</option>
                        <option value="46">Virginia</option>
                        <option value="47">Washington</option>
                        <option value="48">West Virginia</option>
                        <option value="49">Wisconsin</option>
                        <option value="50">Wyoming</option>
                    </select>   
                        <input id="timeataddress" type="text" placeholder="Time at Present Address" />
                        <input id="rent" type="text" placeholder="Monthly Rent/Mortgage Payment" />
                        <input id="jobtitle" type="text" placeholder="Present Job Title" />
                        <input id="employer" type="text" placeholder="Present Employer" />
                        <input id="employerphone" type="text" placeholder="Employer Phone Number" />
                        <input id="jobtime" type="text" placeholder="Time at Present Job" />
                        <input id="grossincome" type="text" placeholder="Monthly Gross Income" />
                        <input id="question-ask" type="submit" value="SUBMIT YOUR APPLICATION" class="btn btn-green" />
                        <div id="details-error"><i class="icon-alert">&nbsp;</i>Please enter all details correctly</div>
                        <div id="form-sent"><i class="icon-check">&nbsp;</i>Message sent, thanks for your enquiry</div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: `$text` is undefined in your PHP file.

Comment: Missing name attributes. Error reporting would have told you that. Plus, what's this? `method = "_POST"`

Comment: what $text is undefined @DaveChen

Comment: [Error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) would have told you "Undefined index..." and "Undefined variable...".

Comment: and if you could point out which attributes are incorrect because I'm still new to this and trying to learn.

Comment: Your code has so many typos. First `$POST` should be `$_POST`. And then when you try and send the message you’re saying it’s in the `$text` variable, but that variable does not exist.

Comment: @MartinBean I have fixed the $_Post now were is this $text variable that everyone is talking about..

Comment: @Mendax ,,,$text is in mail()

Comment: You have many variables defined, but you have not defined `$text` but you are trying to send it in your `mail()` function.   (Also typically, `$_POST` would likely be calling some form variable like `if ($_POST['submit']) { ...}`  assuming that your submit button on your form has name `submit`). As many people here are suggesting, it's probably best to read a tutorial before coming here.  Here's a good example one:  http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you are doing it is wrong.

1.First visit the mail.php file in your browswer  , Check if any error .If there is solve it.

2.If there is no error , its time to debug why its not submitting.I see you are trying to email all the $_post contents to your email.To do so try this

```
     <?php
    if ($_POST) {
        $firstname  = $_POST['firstname'];
        $middleinitial = $_POST['middleinitial'];
        $lastname  = $_POST['lastname'];
        $email2  = $_POST['emailaddress'];
        $form_dob_month  = $_POST['month'];
        $form_dob_day  = $_POST['day'];
        $form_dob_year  = $_POST['year'];
        $social  = $_POST['socialsecurity#'];
        $Driver  = $_POST['driverlicense#'];
        $cellphone  = $_POST['cellphone'];
        $address  = $_POST['streetaddress'];
        $zip  = $_POST['zipcode'];
        $city  = $_POST['city'];
        $form_state  = $_POST['state'];
        $timeataddress  = $_POST['timeatpresentaddress'];
        $rent  = $_POST['monthlyrent/mortgagepayment'];
        $jobtitle  = $_POST['presentjobtitle'];
        $employer  = $_POST['presentemployer'];
        $employerphone  = $_POST['employerphonenumber'];
        $jobtime  = $_POST['timeatpresentjob'];
        $grossincome  = $_POST['monthlygrossincome'];
     }   


$body = $email2.' has submitted some data';
        mail("iamdrivingleads@yahoo.com", "email enquiry", $body,);


?>
```

Comment: thank you so much for the w3 link I now understand what was wrong Thank you so Much!